# How to add Area chart below column chart in ASP.NET charting control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts, charts

I can create a column chart in ASP.NET charting control easily but what I want, is creating stacked background area behind columns to indicate its status. So I thought of creating an Area chart behind it...how could I do this or is there another path should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Chart Samples http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart contains an example of Combination Charts